# Android: Load content on activity load

Tags: android, facebook

I have this code to load a friend list from facebook:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSimpleFacebook = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(this);
}

    final OnFriendsListener mOnFriendsListener = new OnFriendsListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFail(String reason) {
            hideDialog();
            // insure that you are logged in before getting the friends
            Log.w(TAG, reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
            hideDialog();
            Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);
        }


        @Override
        public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {
            // populate list
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Profile profile : friends) {
                values.add(profile.getName());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> friendsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsListAdapter);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        mSimpleFacebook.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data); 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

And i have a button that loads the friendlist when clicked, but i want to launch the friend list immideately when the activity opens without having to click a button, how could i modify the code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can locate facebook loading code in onCreate() method for example 
or you can use Loader and locate code in this method

Comment: How should i use the loader?

Comment: see documentation [link] (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)